# Create own Type Expression in Swift

Tags: xcode, swift, swift2, option-type

Swift has the type `Optional<T>` which can also be expressed as `T?`.

Is it possible to build an own type that an be expressed similarly? For example, instead of `ValueContainer<T>` something like `|T|` or `<<T>>` (or anything else)?

I have tried using operators, but it seems like they only work for values, not for types as such.

Answer (score 2):

IIRC, there are four syntactic sugars for type declarations:

- `T?` for `Optional<T>`
- `T!` for `ImplicitlyUnwrappedOptional<T>`
- `[E]` for `Array<E>`
- `[K:V]` for `Dictionary<K, V>`

They're all built into the compiler — there isn't a language feature for building your own.

But hey, [Swift is open source now](http://swift.org), so there's nothing stopping anyone from building such a language feature. (Getting it accepted by the community for inclusion in mainline Swift might be another matter, though.)